# How to place a Map into another Map in Java

Tags: java, hashmap, maps, nested-map

I'm doing a personal project.

After a lot of maps, I came to the point where I want to enter a map inside another map... Let me explain better.

I have this Map `atPropostas` which have information about a person, but at some time of the program, I want to add to that person a `boss email`.

```
private Map<String, Long> atPropostas;
private Map<String,Map<String,Long>> atOrientadores;
```

To add that `boss email`, I've done this:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Long> atprop : atPropostas.entrySet()) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, Proposta> prop : propostas.entrySet()) {
        if (prop.getValue().getTipo().equals("T2") && propostas.containsKey(atprop.getKey())) {
            atOrientadores.put(prop.getValue().getEmailDocente(), atprop);
        }
    }
}
```

But, `atprop` value, inside `atOrientadores.put()` it produces an error:

> java: incompatible types:
> *java.util.Map.Entry<java.lang.String,java.lang.Long>* cannot be
>
> converted to *java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.Long>*

I have tried to cast the `atprop`:

```
 atOrientadores.put(prop.getValue().getEmailDocente(), (Map<String, Long>) atprop);
```

And the compiler error disappears, but the App itself, doesn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't convert `Map.Entry` in to a `Map` with casting.

*Map* and *entry* represent inherently different notions. *Map* consists of *entries*, it isn't an *entry*.

You can create a *single entry map* by using static method [`Map.ofEntries()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#ofEntries(java.util.Map.Entry...)) available with Java 9

```
atOrientadores.put(prop.getValue().getEmailDocente(), Map.ofEntries(atprop));
```

*Sidenote:* it's highly advisable to use English while giving names to variables, classes, etc. in your application. It makes it easier to reason about your code.

I don't know for sure what `atprop` is meant to represent, but you've mentioned a *person* and an *email*. I advise you to consider creating *classes* that would correspond to a *person* and an *email* instead of complicating your code and dealing with *nested maps*.